# xskak and xelatex

Tags: xetex, xskak

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{skak}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\catcode"2654=\active
\catcode"2655=\active
\catcode"2656=\active
\catcode"2657=\active
\catcode"2658=\active
\catcode"2659=\active

\def\K{\fontspec{FigurineCB AriesSP}\char"00A2}

\let♔\K
\let♕\symqueen
\let♖\symrook
\let♗\symbishop
\let♘\symknight
\let♙\sympawn

\begin{document}


♔♕♖♗♘♙

♔♕♖♗♘♙

\end{document}
```

Why does `xskak` produce an incompatibility error when using XeLaTeX?

```
Error: `\Finv already defined \{mathord}{AMSb}{"60}'
```

`skak` works fine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 3):

This is an incompability from `xunicode` (loaded by `fontspec`/`xltxtra`) and `amsymb` loaded by `chessboard`/`xskak`).

But imho with a current version of `xunicode` the problem should be solved. I don't get the error on miktex 2.9. with

```
\ProvidesFile{xunicode.sty}[2011/09/09 v0.981
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt answer. I have updated the older xunicode.sty, and now it works well. I'm in the process of shifting to XeLatex and to the new, unicode based, WinEdt 7.

Comment: @hhdehaan: I just realized that you are trying to use a system chess font `\fontspec{FigurineCB AriesSP}`. That's okay if you want single, specific symbol from a specific font but I recommend to avoid this. These fonts don't use the standard encoding expected by `skak` and `xskak` and it is not possible to reencode them with `xelatex` (with `lualatex` it will perhaps be possible in the future). It is better to stick to the standard type1 chess fonts.